# Assigning variables to multiple 2-tuples returned from a function in Python

Tags: python, function, tuples

I have a function returning 3 2-tuples. What is the best way to call the function and assign Values1, Values2, Values3 to each tuple, so that I can print, say, (y1, y2) only? I couldn't find any answers that helped me further; thanks!

```
 def function(x, y, z, t):
     x1 = 
     x2 = 
     ...
     z2 = 
     return (x1, x2), (y1, y2), (z1, z2)

 Values1, Values2, Values3 = function(x, y, z, t)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Alternatively, what's wrong with `Values = function(x, y, z, t)` (apart from the too-generic name)?  Usually when you have a bunch of variable names with numbers at the end you really want a list or a dictionary or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to call the function and assign Values1, Values2,
>   Values3 to each tuple, so that I can print, say, (y1, y2) only

If you are only interested in (y1, y2) and would like to ignore the other elements of the tuple, a general convention is to use _ (as a throw away variable name)

```
_, (y1, y2), _ = function(x, y, z, t)
```

another option is to just store the value in a variable and then index it appropriately

```
value = function(x, y, z, t) 
(y1, y2) = value[1]
```

Comment: It is possible to index the return value of the function directly.